# Remove "django_ct" filter query from haystack queries

Tags: django, django-haystack

I have an existing SQL base, which is indexed by Solr. I want to use haystack, because of its abstraction and object creation from queries. The problem is that the haystack search forms and SearchQuerySet always add

```
&fq=django_ct:(appname.model)
```

to the query. Is there a way to remove this from the generated query. There is a way to rename it, but i did not find any way to remove it at all. This query always fails, because there isn't any fq which is called django_ct and why does it has to be there in the first place ?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/issues/1316

Comment: Thanks, but I think this is a bit different. My problem is that i have already indexed db with solr and I want to send queries via haystack.